# Stable Diffusion и ошибка gfpgan

Tags: python

При запуски файла **webui-user.bat** открывается командная строка и начинается процесс установки Stable Diffusion 1.5. Но проходит время и вылезает ошибка. Я пытался искать на разных форумах, но именно такую ошибку найти не смог. Что мне с этим делать?

```
venv "D:\unit\ss\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\Python.exe"
Python 3.10.6 (tags/v3.10.6:9c7b4bd, Aug  1 2022, 21:53:49) [MSC v.1932 64 bit (AMD64)]
Version: v1.4.1
Commit hash: f865d3e11647dfd6c7b2cdf90dde24680e58acd8
Installing gfpgan
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\unit\ss\stable-diffusion-webui\launch.py", line 38, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\unit\ss\stable-diffusion-webui\launch.py", line 29, in main
    prepare_environment()
  File "D:\unit\ss\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\launch_utils.py", line 274, in prepare_environment
    run_pip(f"install {gfpgan_package}", "gfpgan")
  File "D:\unit\ss\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\launch_utils.py", line 130, in run_pip
    return run(f'"{python}" -m pip {command} --prefer-binary{index_url_line}', desc=f"Installing {desc}", errdesc=f"Couldn't install {desc}", live=live)
  File "D:\unit\ss\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\launch_utils.py", line 107, in run
    raise RuntimeError("\n".join(error_bits))
RuntimeError: Couldn't install gfpgan.
Command: "D:\unit\ss\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\python.exe" -m pip install https://github.com/TencentARC/GFPGAN/archive/8d2447a2d918f8eba5a4a01463fd48e45126a379.zip --prefer-binary
Error code: 1
stdout: Collecting https://github.com/TencentARC/GFPGAN/archive/8d2447a2d918f8eba5a4a01463fd48e45126a379.zip

stderr:   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002422BE7A9E0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение')': /TencentARC/GFPGAN/zip/8d2447a2d918f8eba5a4a01463fd48e45126a379
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002422BE7AC80>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение')': /TencentARC/GFPGAN/zip/8d2447a2d918f8eba5a4a01463fd48e45126a379
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002422BE7AE30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение')': /TencentARC/GFPGAN/zip/8d2447a2d918f8eba5a4a01463fd48e45126a379
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002422BE7AFE0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение')': /TencentARC/GFPGAN/zip/8d2447a2d918f8eba5a4a01463fd48e45126a379
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002422BE7B190>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение')': /TencentARC/GFPGAN/zip/8d2447a2d918f8eba5a4a01463fd48e45126a379
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='codeload.github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /TencentARC/GFPGAN/zip/8d2447a2d918f8eba5a4a01463fd48e45126a379 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002422BE7B340>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение'))


Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12119/#12120).